# how to install windows service using Chef Script

Tags: ruby, powershell, service, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Here is the requirement :
I am trying to install a windows service from a remote machine using chef. The script should validate whether that service is already installed or not. If installed then delete and reinstall it.Since i am new to chef am having a tough time finding a solution.

This is what i have tried:

```
execute 'Installing Service TestService' do
        command "sc create \"TestService\" binPath= D:/Deploy/TestService.exe "
        action :run
end
```

it installed the service but I am not able to implement the validation/check if it exists and reinstall. Even I don’t know whether the above script is a standard one. Can someone please help here. 
Also it'll be great if someone can suggest a beginner level chef tutorial for windows dotNet developer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620367/chef-installing-a-windows-service & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131754/chef-how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-service-is-installed

Comment: And for information, since chef 12, the [windows_service](https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_service.html) resource can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the service if it already exists with a `powershell_script` block and notifies the `execute` block to install/reinstall the service. This way the installation will only fire after the service is removed.

```
powershell_script 'delete_if_exist' do
  code <<-EOH
     $Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='TestService'"
     if ($Service) {
        $Service.Delete() 
     }
  EOH
  notifies :run, 'execute[Installing Service TestService]', :immediately
end

execute 'Installing Service TestService' do
  command "sc create \"TestService\" binPath= D:/Deploy/TestService.exe "
  action :nothing
end
```